# Help With issue on pre_get_posts filter in taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, meta-query, pre-get-posts, meta-value

I create a function to filter the taxonomy query with this code

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_taxonomy_query');

$option_taxposts_per_page = get_option('tax_posts_per_page');

function custom_taxonomy_query(&$query)
{
   global $option_taxposts_per_page;

    if (!is_admin() && 
        is_tax('feature') || is_tax('propertytype') || is_tax('location'))  {

            if (is_tax('feature')) {
            $browseorder = get_option('browse_feature_order');
            }
            else if (is_tax('propertytype')) {
            $browseorder = get_option('browse_propertytype_order');
            }
            else if (is_tax('location')) {
            $browseorder = get_option('browse_location_order');
            }

            switch ($browseorder) {
                case "Price Descending":
                    $metakey = '_price';
                    $order = 'DESC';
                    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
                    break;
                case "Price Ascending":
                    $metakey = '_price';
                    $order = 'ASC';
                    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
                    break;
                case "Date Descending":
                    $metakey = '';
                    $order = 'DESC';
                    $orderby = 'date';
                    break;
                case "Date Ascending":
                    $metakey = '';
                    $order = 'ASC';
                    $orderby = 'date';
                    break;
                case "Random":
                    $metakey = '';
                    $order = '';
                    $orderby = 'rand';
                    break;
            }

            $query->set('meta_key', $metakey);
            $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
            $query->set('orderby', $orderby);
            $query->set('order', $order);
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $option_taxposts_per_page);

    }
}
```

the problem is if I choose order by Price Descending and Ascending.. my custom menu navigation gone and I don't know what cause this. If I choose to order by date and random everything work just fine. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning further. I'm running into this same issue when using the pre_get_posts action to sort by a specific order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I was using the wrong technique to create a custom query to my taxonomy instead of using the function above I create new function that use query_vars. Here is the code

```
function taxonomy_posts_order($query) {
    global $browsetype;

    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

    if ( $query->query_vars['taxonomy'] == $term->slug ) 
    {

            switch ($browsetype) {
                case "Price Descending":
                    $metakey = '_price';
                    $order = 'DESC';
                    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
                    break;
                case "Price Ascending":
                    $metakey = '_price';
                    $order = 'ASC';
                    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
                    break;
                case "Date Descending":
                    $metakey = '';
                    $order = 'DESC';
                    $orderby = 'date';
                    break;
                case "Date Ascending":
                    $metakey = '';
                    $order = 'ASC';
                    $orderby = 'date';
                    break;
                case "Random":
                    $metakey = '';
                    $order = '';
                    $orderby = 'rand';
                    break;
            }
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $metakey;
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = $orderby;
        $query->query_vars['order'] = $order;
    }
    return $query;
}
if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'taxonomy_posts_order' );
```